# React-native: onPress action is preventing Swipe action

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native-swipeout` for swiping the card and card should have `onPress` action as well to open a new page.

```
        <Swipeout
            ref={ref => {this.Swipeout[index] = ref}}
            backgroundColor={'transparent'} 
            right={swipeoutBtns}
            scroll={(scrollEnabled) => this.onSwipe(scrollEnabled)}
            sensitivity={1}
            buttonWidth={70}
            onOpen={() => this.onSwipeOpen(index)}
        >   
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onRowClick(item)} title="" style={{ margin: 20}}>
                {this.renderCardItems(item, index)}
            </TouchableOpacity> 
        </Swipeout>
```

Swiping is not working some times since inside card item has `onPress` action. If `TouchableOpacity` is replaced with `View` then Swiping works as expected. I believe as soon as screen is touched `onPress` is called sooner than `Swipeout`.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Are you calling e.preventDefault inside the onRowClick method?

Comment: Try using TouchableWithoutFeedback  as explained by [library](https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout/blob/master/example/SwipeoutExample.js)

Comment: @Firu No change even after using `TouchableWithoutFeedback`

Comment: @RudolfCicko Doing so won't prevent `onPress` action when I indeed required `onPress`?

Comment: Exactly.. that is common mistake. But probably not your case

Comment: @RudolfCicko How can I call `e.preventDefault` exclusively when I require `swipe` action?

Comment: You can use a state in the internal animated (swiped) component, only when the component is in animation do setState({swiped: true}); which in turn will be under the disabled={!this.state.swiped} flag in TouchableOpacity. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TouchableHighlight in your Swipeout tag as below. Then put your card component in the pointed place inside the code. This is working for me on both iOS and Android. Please also install the following timer:

```
import Timer from 'react-native-timer';
```

Then use in the onPress button. So in this way you will avoid the asynchronous problem. 
I hope I could help.

```
onPressFunction=()=>{
 Timer.setTimeout(
                  this, 'modalBottom', () => {

                     //execute your function 

                  }, 200
                );
}
     componentWillUnmount(){
        Timer.clearTimeout('modalBottom');
      }
          render(rowData) {

                // in this part you can design the button in swiped mode

                let swipeBtns = [{
                  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                  component: (<View style={{ flex:1, justifyContent:'center',  alignItems:'center', }}>
                  </View>),

                  onPress: () => { 

                     //execute your function 

                }

                }];
                return (

                  <Swipeout right={swipeBtns}
                  backgroundColor= 'transparent'>
                  <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPressFunction}>
                  <View style={styles.buttonStyle} >

                  ////Put your card component here

                  </View>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                  </Swipeout>

                );
              }
            }
```

Comment: No Change. Still sometimes `Swipe` action is missing and `TouchableHighlight` is taking place which is not desired behaviour.

Comment: @Kishore:That is strange. Are you doing this in Android or iOS?

Comment: android. as soon as screen is touched onPress is called sooner than Swipeout. Is my assumption valid?

Comment: @Kishore: I found an easy way, Just put this beautiful timer there :)

Comment: `TouchableHighlight` is anyway called since Timer is inside the `onPress`. But my intention is not to delaying the `onPress` action, But 'TouchableHighlight' should not takes place at all as long as `Swipe` action is performed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187248/discussion-between-kishore-and-reza).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is even sipler way to achieve this :-)

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressOut={() => onPress()} delayPressOut={500}>
```